# Slic3r causes Ubuntu 18.04 to hang on Macbook Pro

Tags: 18.04, macbook-pro

My laptop freezes when running [Slic3r](https://slic3r.org/) app on Ubuntu 18.04  to prepare a 3d print. I had opened a ticket on the slic3r app site and provided a copy of the file, but they were able to process the file.  It could be a hardware issue on my Ubuntu laptop, but I have been unable to determine if that is the case.

Notes / what I have tried:

- When it hangs, the cursor initially moves but clicking anything has no effect
- Alt-tab  does not switch apps, and control-alt-T cannot open a terminal
- Only solution has been to hard shutdown holding power button
- I booted another notebook (Acer with broken screen) using "TRY UBUNTU" , and ran the same copy of the Appimage that caused the macbook to hang, that Acer laptop running same copy of Ubuntu was able to process the file
- I tried booting the Macbook pro also booting from "TRY UBUNTU" (hoping to find I had an installation issue) but it still froze the computer
- Other than the system hanging when running the slic3r app, the Macbook pro running Ubuntu 18.04 works very well
- No issues were found running memtester
- No bad spots were found on disk
- Installed and ran `stress`, I don't fully understand the tool but could not see any issues running verbose
- Viewing `htop` when it hanged, it was  using < 1G out of 4G memory, SWAP was not active, CPUs both < 80%

**Correction**: Using control-alt-f1 I was able to switch to tty and kill the Slicer app which unfroze the machine. However, I still cannot understand why the app freezes the Macbook running Ubuntu 18.04 but not the Acer running the same OS.

**Update**: Using control-alt-f1 sometimes works, sometimes does not requiring hard shutdown.
I am new to Linux, and at this point I am stumped. Does anyone know what I can try to determine what is causing the Macbook Pro to hang with this app?

**Update**: I have opened an issue on the Github slicer site, but given that I can run it successfully on Ubuntu 18.04 on a different machine it looks like it is something specific to this Macbook Pro
`cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=08e94ee0-7ddf-49b3-ba02-5de27987fd9a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8141-EF73  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation, commented out by me below and replaced with file
#UUID=67dcee39-a510-46b3-bbb4-b4b4885676af none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile                                  none            swap    sw              0       0 

//192.168.1.55/SharedData  /media/DS_Share cifs credentials=/home/
merlin/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0 0

//192.168.1.55/SherLinux /media/SherLinuxBackup cifs credentials=/home/merlin/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0 0

//192.168.1.55/music /media/DS_Music cifs credentials=/home/merlin/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0 0

//192.168.1.55/photo /media/DS_Pictures cifs credentials=/home/merlin/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0 0

//192.168.1.55/Budget /media/DS_Budget cifs credentials=/home/merlin/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0 0
```

`free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.6G        1.2G        1.2G         76M        1.2G        2.2G
Swap:          8.0G          0B        8.0G
```

**Update**: Ran: `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`. Output: `vm.swappiness=80`

Reran slicer app which froze the macbook. Ctrl-Alt-F1 did not switch to tty, hard boot was required

`parted`:

```
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54503 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      105MB  734MB  629MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      734MB  316GB  315GB   ext4
 3      316GB  320GB  4022MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

`free -h`:

I struggled with this request. when system freezes, only thing that works is hard reset which loses everything. nothing works. 
To try and answer the request, I ran this script output to log file:

```
for (( ; ; ))
do
   free -h
   date +%c
   sleep 1
done
```

Here is the output of the last few entries before it froze:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.6G        1.4G        1.2G         60M        1.0G        1.9G
Swap:          8.0G          0B        8.0G
Mon 27 May 2019 05:13:56 PM EDT

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.6G        1.4G        1.2G         60M        1.0G        1.9G
Swap:          8.0G          0B        8.0G
Mon 27 May 2019 05:13:57 PM EDT

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.6G        1.4G        1.2G         60M        1.0G        1.9G
Swap:          8.0G          0B        8.0G
Mon 27 May 2019 05:13:58 PM EDT

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.6G        1.4G        1.2G         60M        1.0G        1.9G
Swap:          8.0G          0B        8.0G
Mon 27 May 2019 05:13:59 PM EDT
```

After that it froze requiring hard reboot

**How I created SWAP:**

I followed these instructions:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-use-swap-file-instead-of-swap.html

The system is single boot. OSX is no longer installed. 
Output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` is `MBP53.88Z.00AC.B03.0906151647`,
the firmware on the apple site seems to have a different format.

I found an EFI Firmware 1.9 update that might be relevant. it refers to 320GB drive (which matches mine) correcting issue that causes intermittent freezing... I downloaded the update (`MacbookProEFIUpdate.DMG`), but I am not sure how to install the firmware. When I attempt to connect to `/boot/efi` I get a permission denied message.

Comment: @SteveNelson Sorry for the delay. Since you don't have OSX installed, I'm not sure how to install the EFI and SMC firmware updates. If you have an Apple store near you, go talk to an Apple Genius, and ask how to do the updates without OSX. They may temporarily swap in a hard drive with OSX on it, so they can do the updates for you. I'm pretty sure that these updates are going to be necessary to get your machine running properly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94182/discussion-on-question-by-steve-nelson-slic3r-causes-ubuntu-18-04-to-hang-on-mac).

Comment: Please do keep me posted, ok?